# Как резервировать 3-ее измерение 3-ёхмерного массива вручную?

Tags: java, массивы

> При резервировании памяти под многомерный массив необходимо указать память
>   только для первого (левого) измерения массива. А для каждого из остальных
>   измерений массива память можно резервировать отдельно. Г.Шилдт

Объясняется это на примере 2-ухмерного массива,вот фрагмент:

```
int twoD [ ] [ ] = new i n t [ 4 ] [ ] ;

twoD [ O ]=new int [ 5 ] ;

twoD [ l ]=new int [ 5 ] ;
```

А как инициализировать вручную в трёхмерном массиве третье измерение,ведь если сделаем по типу сверху,то зададим только 2-ое измерение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно резервировать память под каждый массив второго/третьего уровня отдельно, но не обязательно. Вот такой код вполне легитимен:

```
int[][] two = new int[5][5];
int[][][] three = new int[5][5][5];
```

Инициализируем отдельно второй уровень двумерного массива:

```
    int[][] two = new int[5][];
    int size = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
        two[i] = new int[size];
    }
```

Инициализируем отдельно второй и третий уровни трехмерного массива:

```
    int[][][] three = new int[5][][];
    for (int i = 0; i < three.length; i++) {
        three[i] = new int[size][];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < three.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < three[i].length; j++) {
            three[i][j] = new int[size];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это я читал,просто написано,что для всех многомерных массивов достаточно инициализировать лишь первое измерение,а остальные можно вручную:вот мне и стало интересно,как это сделать

Comment: Дополнил ответ с примерами

Comment: Вроде понял,то есть для 4-ёхмерного продолжение будет таким?                                                                                                                          for(int i = 0;i < three.length; i++) {for (int j = 0; j < three[i].length; j++){ for(int z = 0;z < three.length; z++){  three[i][j][z]=new int[size];   }}}

Comment: Да, все верно. Причем размерность каждого уровня массивов (и даже отдельных массивов на одном уровне) не обязательно должна быть равна size. Это не матрица, а просто массив массивов, поэтому размерность может быть у каждого массива своя. Все зависит от логики вашего приложения.

Comment: Не заметил three[i].lenght.Смутило three[i]-это элемент 2-го измерения массива,у которого запрашиваем длину(но как и зачем?), или мы так узнаём количество символов во  втором измерении и нас не напрягает итерация i ?

Comment: @Alabushka у вас ведь может быть three[0].lenght == 5, а three[1].jenght == 6. Это не обязательно квадратная матрица, а массив массивов, как я уже говорил выше.